# Based on items in my list the eventListener is excuted

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an array and add item to it. Each item has delete button (some thing like To-Do-List). When the delete icon is pressed, an event is triggered and the item should be removed from the list and DOM. But when I press the first item's delete icon it is executed **several times (depending on how many items are in the list)** as a result the last item is only excepted **once**.

```
const arr = [];
addTodo.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const todoTxt = document.querySelector(".input--form__txt").firstElementChild;
  // console.log(todoTxt);
  const c1 = new CreateTodo(todoTxt.value);
  arr.push(c1);
  document.querySelector(".input--form__txt").firstElementChild.value = "";
  let newLi = document.createElement(`li`);
  newLi.classList.add("todoitem");
  newLi.innerHTML = `<span class="todoitem--subject">${c1.title}</span>
  <span class="todoitem--detail">
    <span class="todoitem--detail__date">${c1.createdAt[0]}</span>
    <span class="todoitem--detail__select">
    <input type="checkbox" onchange="checkboxstatus(this)" value="${c1.id}"/></span>
    <span class="todoitem--detail__delete">
    <img src="./Assets/Img/trash.svg" alt=""/>
    </span>
  </span>`;
  toDoList.appendChild(newLi);
  deleteIcon = document.querySelectorAll(".todoitem--detail__delete");
  deleteIcon.forEach((de, index) => {
    de.addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log("mine", index);
    });
  });

  console.log(arr);
});
```

I am a very beginner in JavaScript and trying to understand and worry about the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need all the event listeners when using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation). It means you create a handling method and assign a listener at a level above the level where you want events on elements to be handled (easiest: `document` level). Within that handler you determine where the event came from (its `target`) and act accordingly.

For deleting rows in a `<ul>` list, here's a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

addDemoList();

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.closest(`.del`)) {
    // button with className '.del' clicked,
    // so remove the row.
    return evt.target.closest(`li`).remove();
  }
}

function addDemoList() {
  const ul = document.body.insertAdjacentElement(
    `beforeend`, 
    Object.assign(document.createElement(`ul`), {id: `ulTst`}) );
  for (let i = 0; i < 20; i += 1) {
    const nwLi = ul.insertAdjacentElement(`beforeend`, 
      Object.assign(document.createElement(`li`), {textContent: `Row ${i+1}`}));
    nwLi.insertAdjacentHTML(`beforeend`, ` <button class="del">delete</button>`);  
  }
}
```

Here's a [more extensive example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-dbn5wb?file=TodoFactory.js) of a todo list.

Answer (score 1):

Items are deleted multiple times because event listeners for all of the items are being added to all the delete buttons when it's clicked, so the first delete button has a lot of event listeners that are the same after multiple items have been added, and, to put it simply, the wrong things are happening when the delete buttons are being clicked.

You can use [`element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) to fix this, I believe (you don't just have to use `document`). In this case, you can select delete buttons inside where you put the new list item, not the entire document like it did before. So only the elements we want to have the event listener will have it, and not any other elements that already have them.

Here's my full solution:

```js
const arr = [];
addTodo.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const todoTxt = document.querySelector(".input--form__txt").firstElementChild;
  // console.log(todoTxt);
  const c1 = new CreateTodo(todoTxt.value);
  arr.push(c1);
  document.querySelector(".input--form__txt").firstElementChild.value = "";
  let newLi = document.createElement(`li`);
  newLi.classList.add("todoitem");
  newLi.innerHTML = `<span class="todoitem--subject">${c1.title}</span>
  <span class="todoitem--detail">
    <span class="todoitem--detail__date">${c1.createdAt[0]}</span>
    <span class="todoitem--detail__select">
    <input type="checkbox" onchange="checkboxstatus(this)" value="${c1.id}"/></span>
    <span class="todoitem--detail__delete">
    <img src="./Assets/Img/trash.svg" alt=""/>
    </span>
  </span>`;
  toDoList.appendChild(newLi);
  /* I changed this bit */
  // Selects elements inside newLi with that query selector
  deleteIcon = newLi.querySelector(".todoitem--detail__delete");
  de.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("mine", index);
  });

  console.log(arr);
});
```

As for performance, this solution should be faster than yours, particuarly on longer lists (however longer lists still do affect performance)

Answer (score 1):

Since it's tricky delegating event listeners to elements created after the page loads, you can set the listener to the entire document, then get the closest parent element on click, and if its a delete button, execute the code:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", e => 
{
    const target = e.target.closest('.delete'); 

  if(target)
  {
     console.log(target.closest('li').textContent);
  }
 });
```

```html
<ul>
<li>
  Item 1
  <button class="delete">Delete</button>
</li>
<li>
  Item 2
  <button class="delete">Delete</button>
</li>
<li>
  Item 3
  <button class="delete">Delete</button>
</li>
<li>
  Item 4
  <button class="delete">Delete</button>
</li>
<li>
  Item 5
  <button class="delete">Delete</button>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

As the others have mentioned [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) - adding *one* listener to a parent element to catch events from its children as they "bubble up" the DOM - is the best route to take. While the other examples attach the listener at the `document` level this example attaches it to the common parent - the list (`ul`) element.

There is an additional point that you may find useful - this example uses the data to drive the changes in the UI. For example, clicking a delete button doesn't immediately remove the list item from the DOM; it removes the todo from the `todos` array first and *then* re-renders the list using that changed data. In addition: clicking the checkbox causes a change to the data (the `done` property on the todo instance toggles `true`/`false`) which is then used to determine the checked value of the input element when the list item is re-rendered.

```js
// Cache the elements
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const list = document.querySelector('ul');

// Add listeners to the button and the list elements
button.addEventListener('click', handleAddTodo)
list.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

// Define todos (`let` rather than `const`
// because we're going to be reassigning filtered/mapped
// arrays back to it to ensure consistency)
let todos = [];

// Create a date formatter
const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB');

input.focus();

// Todo constructor - adapted from your example
function Todo(value) {
  this.id = self.crypto.randomUUID();
  this.title = value;
  this.createdAt = formatter.format(new Date());
  this.done = false;
}

// When a todo is added grab the value from
// the input element and, if it's not an empty
// string, create a Todo instance, and push it
// into the todos array
// THEN call the renderTodos function with 
// the todos array
function handleAddTodo(e) {
  const { value } = input;
  if (value) {
    const todo = new Todo(value);
    todos.push(todo);
    input.value = '';
  }
  renderTodos(todos);
  input.focus();
}

// If there are todos in the array `map` over
// the array to generate an array of HTML strings
// which are joined into one string and then added as
// the HTML for the list
function renderTodos(todos) {
  if (todos.length) {
    const html = todos.map(todo => {
      
      // Note that we define our class list using
      // a joined array: `todo` is the main class, and
      // then we add the `strike` class if the todo.done
      // property is true
      const classes = [ 'todo', todo.done && 'strike' ].join(' ');
      
      // Again we use the todo object to define whether the
      // the todo's checkbox should be checked or not
      return `
        <li data-id=${todo.id} class="${classes}">
          <div>
            <span class="title">${todo.title}</span>
            <span class="created">${todo.createdAt}</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              class="done"
              type="checkbox"
              ${todo.done && "checked"}
            />
            <button
              type="button"
              class="delete"
            >X</button>
          </div>
        </li>
      `;
    }).join('');
    list.innerHTML = html;
  } else {
    list.innerHTML = '';  
  }
}

function handleClick(e) {
  
  // If the `delete` button is clicked we find the
  // id on the closest list item, we use that id to filter
  // that todo from the array, and then re-render the list
  if (e.target.matches('.delete')) {
    const { id } = e.target.closest('li').dataset;
    todos = todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== id);
    renderTodos(todos);
  }

  // If the clicked element is the `done` checkbox we
  // find the id on the closest list item, and then `map`
  // over the array (to produce a new array). If the id matches
  // the current iterated todo we change the `done` property
  // to true or false determined by the current value of the
  // clicked elements `checked` value
  if (e.target.matches('.done')) {
    const { id } = e.target.closest('li').dataset;
    todos = todos.map(todo => {
      if (todo.id === id) {
        return { ...todo, done: e.target.checked };
      }
      return todo;
    });
    renderTodos(todos);
  }

}
```

```css
ul { width: 250px; }
.todo { display: flex; padding: 0.25rem; }
.delete { color: red; }
.todo div span:nth-child(2) { margin-left: 0.5rem; }
.todo div:nth-child(2) { margin-left: auto; }
.delete:hover, input[type=checkbox]:hover  { cursor: pointer; }
.strike { text-decoration: line-through; }
```

```html
<input />
<button type="button">Add todo</button>
<ul></ul>
```

Additional documentation

- [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat)
- [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [randomUUID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/randomUUID)
- [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)
- [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)
- [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)
- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your solutions. I wrote mine but i used your hints and absolutely they helped me. I put my solution maybe help the other beginners.

```
    const arr = [];
addTodo.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const todoTxt = document.querySelector(".input--form__txt").firstElementChild;
  // console.log(todoTxt);
  const c1 = new CreateTodo(todoTxt.value);
  arr.push(c1);
  document.querySelector(".input--form__txt").firstElementChild.value = "";
  let newLi = document.createElement(`li`);
  newLi.classList.add("todoitem");
  newLi.innerHTML = `<span class="todoitem--subject">${c1.title}</span>
  <span class="todoitem--detail">
    <span class="todoitem--detail__date">${c1.createdAt[0]}</span>
    <span class="todoitem--detail__select">
    <input type="checkbox" onchange="checkboxstatus(this)" value="${c1.id}"/></span>
    <span class="todoitem--detail__delete">
    <img src="./Assets/Img/trash.svg" alt=""/>
    </span>
  </span>`;
  toDoList.appendChild(newLi);
  deleteIcon = newLi.querySelector(".todoitem--detail__delete");
  deleteIcon.addEventListener("click", removeItem);

});
function removeItem(e) {
  let getLi = e.target.closest("li");
  let rowid = Number(getLi.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]").value);

  const findIndex = arr.findIndex((item) => {
    return item.id === rowid;
  });
  arr.splice(findIndex, 1);
  e.target.closest("li").remove();

}
```